# what does the keyword "/8836-DAE0/" 'denotes in DirectoryPath=/storage/8836-DAE0/System Volume Information ' in android logcat logs

Tags: media, crash-reports, crash-dumps, android-storage, android-automotive

I am working to debug a usb crash in android infotainment system . I wanted to know ,what does the keyword "/8836-DAE0/" 'denotes in DirectoryPath=/storage/8836-DAE0/System Volume Information ' in android logcat logs ?

Answer (score 0):

This 4 byte number looks like a FAT32 Volume Serial Number to me. It is part of the file system and stored in the boot sector at offset 67.